# Where can i get all the commands with descriptions for Bitcoind on my linux server?

Tags: bitcoind, api, json-rpc

Just installed bitcoind on my server and wanted to find a cheat sheet for the bitcoind commands. Where would i find them with a description and example of what each command does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These days the most thorough and handy guide for the Bitcoin Core RPC commands is the [bitcoin.org developer reference page](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#rpc-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you are looking for something like [the API calls list](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list) or [Running Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin). Another option (suggested by Pieter Wuille) is to use `bitcoind help` command.

Comment: yep, that's about everything there is to BTC. Alt-coins may be different.
Up voted Salvador's answer

Answer (score 4):

Use `bitcoin-cli help` to get a list of all RPC commands.
Use `bitcoin-cli help <command>` to get information about RPC command `<command>`.

Comment: I installed bitcoind on my ubuntu-Server with "apt-get install bitcoind". When I enter "bitcoind help" I get this answer: "error: couldn't connect to server".